# Use square brackets on extended events filter

Tags: sql-server, syntax, extended-events, like, operator

I want create an extended events session and use the `like_i_sql_unicode_string` operator to filter the phrase `[demo]`, with the square brackets.
I've started with:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [demo] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_completed(
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[like_i_sql_unicode_string]([sqlserver].[sql_text],N'%[demo]%'))
)
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer
alter event session [demo] on server state=start
```

But this interprets `[demo]` as a character group on a regex-like syntax. So if I run this:

```
-- m
```

It will be captured on the extended event.

The closest I've got was filtering it later, using `[sqlserver].[like_i_sql_unicode_string]([sqlserver].[sql_text],N'%demo%')` on the filter and then:

```
SELECT
n.ev.value('@timestamp','datetimeoffset') as [timestamp],
n.ev.value('data[@name="batch_text"][1]','varchar(max)')  as [batch_text]
FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets xet
INNER JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions xe ON xe.[address] = xet.event_session_address
cross apply (select CONVERT(XML, target_data) as xData ) as x
cross apply x.xData.nodes(N'RingBufferTarget/event') AS n(ev)
WHERE xe.name = N'demo' AND xet.target_name = N'ring_buffer'
and n.ev.value('data[@name="batch_text"][1]','varchar(max)') like '%\[demo\]%' escape '\'
```

But this still captures more events than necessary.

I've tried `'%[[]demo[]]%'`, `'%{[}demo{]}%'`, `'%\[demo\]%'`, `'%$[demo$]%'`, and none of those worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was challenging.

```
WHERE 
    [sqlserver].[like_i_sql_unicode_string]([sqlserver].[sql_text], N'%[[]demo]%')
```

When testing it, even the opening bracket is regarded as a [[ ] (Wildcard - Character(s) to Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/wildcard-character-s-to-match-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

So the first part of the condition has the opening bracket nested.
The closing bracket alone is not recognized as a special character, so no extra care is needed.

Together both these conditions surround the searched text.

This is documented under [Using Wildcard Characters As Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql#using-wildcard-characters-as-literals) in the documentation for [LIKE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) (emphasis added):

> You can use the wildcard pattern matching characters as literal characters. To use a wildcard character as a literal character, enclose the wildcard character in brackets. The following table shows several examples of using the LIKE keyword and the [ ] wildcard characters.
>
> | **Symbol** | **Meaning** |
> | --- | --- |
> | LIKE '5[%]' | 5% |
> | LIKE '[_]n' | _n |
> | LIKE '[a-cdf]' | a, b, c, d, or f |
> | LIKE '[-acdf]' | -, a, c, d, or f |
> | **LIKE '[ [ ]'** | **[** |
> | LIKE ']' | ] |
> | LIKE 'abc[_]d%' | abc_d and abc_de |
> | LIKE 'abc[def]' | abcd, abce, and abcf |

**Test**

```
SELECT ('a_demo_a')
GO
SELECT ('a_[demo_a')
GO
SELECT ('a_demo]_a')
GO
SELECT ('a_[demo]_a')
GO
SELECT ('m')
GO
SELECT ('a_[[demo]_a')
```

**Result**
[image]